# On the integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\ \sqrt[4]{1-x\,\gamma^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2\gamma}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, elliptic-curves, experimental-mathematics

V. Reshetnikov gave the [interesting integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541135/conjecture-int-01-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt1-x-sqrt4x-sqrt42-x-sqrt),

$$\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\ \sqrt[4]{2-x\,\sqrt3}}=\frac{2\,\sqrt2}{3\,\sqrt[8]3}\pi\tag1$$

After some experimentation, it turns out that more generally, given some integer/rational $N$, we are to find an algebraic number $\gamma$ that solves,

> $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\ \sqrt[4]{1-x\,\gamma^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2\gamma}}\tag2$$

(*Compare to the similar integral in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037060/on-reshetnikovs-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x).*) Equivalently, to find $\gamma$ such that,

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{N}
&=I\left(\gamma^2;\ \tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)\\[1.8mm]
&= \frac{B\left(\gamma^2;\ \tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)}{B\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)}
\end{aligned} \tag3$$

with [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $B(a,b)$, [incomplete beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B(z;a,b)$ and [regularized beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html) $I(z;a,b)$, and $B\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}$. Reshetnikov's example, after tweaking, was just the case $N=\frac{3}{2}$ and $\gamma=\frac{3^{1/4}}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Solutions for prime $N=2,3,5,7$ are known. Let $v=\gamma$, then,
$$-1 + 2 v^2 = 0\quad\quad  N=2\\ - 1 + 2 v + 2 v^2 = 0\quad\quad  N=3\\ - 1 + 8 v - 4 v^2 - 8 v^3 + 4 v^4 = 0\quad\quad  N=5$$
etc, with $N=7$ using a $12$-deg equation. I found these using *Mathematica*'s *FindRoot* command but, unlike [the other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037060/on-reshetnikovs-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x), I couldn't find a nice common form for $\gamma$. (The pattern of this family is also different. I had expected $N=7$ to also involve a sextic only.)

> **Q:** Is it true one can find algebraic number $\gamma$ for all prime $N$? What is it for $N=11$?

---

**Update, Aug 16, 2019**

In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039091/why-do-these-two-integrals-use-roots-of-reciprocal-polynomials?noredirect=1#comment6841145_2039091), Reshetnikov gave the explicit solution to,

$$I\left(\gamma^2;\ \tfrac14,\tfrac14\right) = \tfrac17$$
as,
$$\small\gamma = \frac16\left(5\cos x-\sqrt3\sin x-1-\sqrt3\sqrt{7+4\sqrt7-(11+2\sqrt7)\cos x+\sqrt3(5+2\sqrt7)\sin x}\right)$$
where $x = \tfrac13\arccos\big(\tfrac{13}{14}\big)$.

**P.S.** I forgot I also found $\gamma$ in this [2016 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041898/on-the-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt4x-sqrt41-x-sqrt1-x-beta2) as,

$$\gamma = \tfrac12\left(2\cos\tfrac{2\pi}7-\sqrt{2\cos\tfrac{4\pi}7+\sqrt2\csc\tfrac{9\pi}{28}}\right)$$

Comment: Where is Ramanujan when you need him?

Comment: @martycohen: I'm sure his modern-day equivalent is working in the more lucrative IT sector.  :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Since you beat me to the answer for [2037060](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037060/on-reshetnikovs-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x?noredirect=1&lq=1), I tried this one instead.  It appears that a degree 30 polynomial gives such a $ \gamma $ for $ N = 11 $.

Comment: Also in equation (3), I think you mean $ B(\gamma^2; 1/4, 1/4) \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma^2(1/4)} $.

Comment: @StevenCharlton:Typo has been corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking $ \gamma $ to be the smallest positive root (the 4th root according to Mathematica) of the degree 30 polynomial
\begin{align*}
  f(x) = -1 + 30 x + 170 x^2 + 672 x^3 - 6956 x^4 - 6808 x^5 + 
  42872 x^6 - 56576 x^7 - 241616 x^8 + 712800 x^9 + 
  1099296 x^{10} - 2718208 x^{11} - 3427264 x^{12} + 5028992 x^{13} + 
  8030592 x^{14} - 3956736 x^{15} - 14783232 x^{16} - 2065920 x^{17} + 
  20241920 x^{18} + 7954432 x^{19} - 19317760 x^{20} - 7817216 x^{21} + 
  12445696 x^{22} + 3342336 x^{23} - 5435392 x^{24} - 122880 x^{25} + 
  1662976 x^{26} - 393216 x^{27} - 344064 x^{28} + 98304 x^{29} + 
  32768 x^{30}
\end{align*}
seems to give a solution for $ N = 11 $.

Comment: +1. I trust this result. Its discriminant is a neat power $d=2^{870}\times11^{29}$, the leading coefficient is $2^{15}$, and its reciprocal $f(1/x)=f(y)=0$ is the minpoly of the related $I(y^2;1/2,1/4)=\frac{1}{11}$ as discussed in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039091/why-do-these-two-integrals-use-roots-of-reciprocal-polynomials).

Comment: Furthermore, if $u=(x_4+x_{10}+x_{17}+x_{18}+x_{19}+x_{20})/2$ using the root ordering of _Mathematica_, then $u$ is a root of  $-23 - 343u + 390 u^2 - 42u^3 - 15u^4 + u^5=0$ which is a solvable quintic with a cyclic Galois group. A random $f(x)$ will not have all these properties.

Answer (score 11):

> For any rational $0<r<1$, there exists an algebraic $\gamma$ such that
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt[4]{1-x\,\gamma^2}}=r\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2\gamma}}$$
>   Such $\gamma$ can always be expressed by radicals.

---

Following the first half of Achille hui's solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541135), we have
$$F(\mu ) = \int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{\sqrt[4]{x}\sqrt {1 - x} \sqrt[4]{{1 - \mu x}}}}dx}  = \frac{{4\sqrt 2 {\pi ^{3/2}}}}{{{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})}}\frac{1}{{{\mu ^{1/4}}}}\int_0^\omega  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 + {t^4}} }}dt} $$
with $\omega  = {\left( {\frac{\mu }{{1 - \mu }}} \right)^{1/4}}$,
let $\zeta = e^{i\pi/4}$, then 
$$F(\mu) = \frac{{4\sqrt 2 {\pi ^{3/2}}}}{{{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})}}\frac{\zeta }{{{\mu ^{1/4}}}}\int_0^{\omega \zeta } {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {t^4}} }}dt} $$

Now let $\wp(z)$ be the Weierstrass elliptic function with $g_2 = 1,g_3 = 0$, its periods are $\{\lambda, \lambda i\}$ where $\lambda = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt \pi  }}{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})$, and 
$$x = \sqrt 2 \int_0^{1/\sqrt {2\wp (x)} } {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - {t^4}} }}dt} $$
modulo an appropriate period lattice. 
Therefore, 
$$\omega \zeta  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\wp (\lambda r)} }}\implies F(\mu ) = \frac{{4\sqrt 2 {\pi ^{3/2}}}}{{{\Gamma ^2}(\frac{1}{4})}}\frac{\zeta }{{{\mu ^{1/4}}}}\frac{{\lambda r}}{{\sqrt 2 }} = 2\pi r\frac{\zeta }{{{\mu ^{1/4}}}}$$
Replace $\mu$ by $\gamma^2$ gives
$${\gamma ^2} = \frac{1}{{1 - 4{\wp ^2}(\lambda r)}}\implies F({\gamma ^2}) = \frac{{2\pi }}{{\sqrt {2\gamma } }}r(1 + i)$$

Take $r = (1-i)/22$, which corresponds with your $N=11$, gives $${\gamma ^2} = \frac{1}{{1 - 4{\wp ^2}(\lambda \frac{{1 - i}}{{22}})}}$$
$\wp(\lambda r)$ here is a $22$-torsion of elliptic curve $E:y^2 = 4x^3-x$, it is then routine to verify that $\gamma$ indeed satisfies the desired equation.

Note that $E$ has complex multiplication by $i$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)/\mathbb{Q}$ is always an abelian extension for any $r$.

---

For $N=13$, the minimal polynomial for $\gamma$ is $$262144 x^{36}-524288 x^{35}-4456448 x^{34}-2621440 x^{33}+20381696 x^{32}+41418752 x^{31}-40894464 x^{30}-170655744 x^{29}+41484288 x^{28}+370671616 x^{27}-49610752 x^{26}-499843072 x^{25}+160481280 x^{24}+460292096 x^{23}-379060224 x^{22}-328843264 x^{21}+535066624 x^{20}+219197440 x^{19}-480704512 x^{18}-146997248 x^{17}+279806464 x^{16}+89368576 x^{15}-101117952 x^{14}-45646848 x^{13}+19158272 x^{12}+19104768 x^{11}-151808 x^{10}-5997824 x^9-834624 x^8+1179264 x^7+214528 x^6-105280 x^5-24924 x^4+2456 x^3+412 x^2+40 x-1 = 0$$

For $N=15$, the minimal polynomial for $\gamma$ is

```
1-64 x-96 x^2+128 x^3-5600 x^4-13504 x^5+86144 x^6+66176 x^7-697408 x^8-3584 x^9+3053056 x^10-1106944 x^11-7039488 x^12+5483520 x^13+7354368 x^14-15812608 x^15+1345024 x^16+32538624 x^17-9871360 x^18-47906816 x^19+778240 x^20+46448640 x^21+20676608 x^22-25067520 x^23-29114368 x^24+2752512 x^25+18481152 x^26+4980736 x^27-5636096 x^28-2883584 x^29+524288 x^30+524288 x^31+65536 x^32
```

For $N=17$, the minimal polynomial is

```
1-80 x-288 x^2-7472 x^3+263520 x^4-1834944 x^5+7949120 x^6+9713984 x^7-133644672 x^8-24257792 x^9+562386944 x^10+2302738688 x^11+482554368 x^12-46943337472 x^13-7480857600 x^14+435187680256 x^15-25017156608 x^16-2451637374976 x^17+749950640128 x^18+9497241620480 x^19-7627550072832 x^20-26814443339776 x^21+50357313683456 x^22+56935237042176 x^23-233656552685568 x^24-96787065536512 x^25+794987687837696 x^26+168511477186560 x^27-2052161595637760 x^28-434303530696704 x^29+4129721034735616 x^30+1386031936176128 x^31-6608987067383808 x^32-3909549495943168 x^33+8496901307498496 x^34+8840840062435328 x^35-8705679109914624 x^36-15919713150304256 x^37+6741308655796224 x^38+22995053303562240 x^39-3118665184575488 x^40-26813854742740992 x^41-784242774638592 x^42+25326363753840640 x^43+3450707285901312 x^44-19377307395293184 x^45-4143992149114880 x^46+11962939040858112 x^47+3281065036742656 x^48-5905464873189376 x^49-1905340371173376 x^50+2291962858176512 x^51+830419578650624 x^52-678683215921152 x^53-271245438353408 x^54+144941187596288 x^55+65689377308672 x^56-19666655248384 x^57-11630771437568 x^58+1026497183744 x^59+1468878815232 x^60+120259084288 x^61-120259084288 x^62-17179869184 x^63+4294967296 x^64
```

Comment: A partially simplified _Mathematica_ expression for the 32-degree root (for $N=15$) is [here](https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/ddc81559880a7ff8175d4207c7e4d82e). I think that further simplification is possible.

Comment: My first attempt at simplification of the 36-degree root is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/e7f41791d7d755b6b558289be8e2f44f/raw/df6d2df0f03dd452f453868f2b9288989a859111/Root.m). Certainly, much more can be done there.

Comment: My next attempt at simplification of the 36-degree root is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/c8562d4a75c8b6accbe33d31ca5a4552/raw/0f60a56ab5c3d1b9033461244d3dbc5693da5301/Root.m). From $22087$ characters down to $2131$. Perhaps, it can be simplified even further.

Comment: For $N=17$, an explicit expression can be obtained as a solution of [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/ccbdfbd463adf1aece004c450361d713/raw/99d095bc6bbf467b62ec0e53e981682ef9715f3f/Quartic.m) quartic equation with algebraic coefficients in radicals.

Answer (score 5):

Remarkably, the root of the 30-degree equation in question $\small(\gamma \approx 0.028402981583...)$ has an elementary closed form. Let
$$
\small
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac15\,\arccos\left(\frac{255300649+251245525 \sqrt{5}}{4\cdot11^8}\right),\\
\beta &= \sqrt{25085-6802 \sqrt{5}},\\[1mm]
\kappa &= 11  \cdot \beta\,\sin\alpha,\\[2mm]
\lambda &= \beta \, \sin 2\alpha,\\[2mm]
\mu &= 11\cdot 811 \cos\alpha,\\[2mm]
\nu &= 811 \cos 2\alpha,\\[2mm]
\eta &= 11^3\cdot811 \left(55-14 \sqrt{11}\right)\\
&-11\,\kappa\left(2474+1479 \sqrt{5}-763 \sqrt{11}-385 \sqrt{55}\right)+ \lambda\left(22127+140925 \sqrt{5}+3421 \sqrt{11}-35431 \sqrt{55}\right)\\
&-11\, \mu\left(365 + 38 \sqrt{5} - 107 \sqrt{11} - 9 \sqrt{55}\right)- \nu\left(39510-14118 \sqrt{5} - 12837 \sqrt{11} + 3179 \sqrt{55}\right)\!,\\[2mm]
\rho &=11^3\cdot811 \left(\sqrt{11} - 3\right)\\
&+4 \, \kappa \left(1397+132 \sqrt{5}-466 \sqrt{11}+122 \sqrt{55}\right) + \lambda \left(46291+43551 \sqrt{5}-9923 \sqrt{11}-9501 \sqrt{55}\right) \\
&-2 \, \mu \left(638 + 22 \sqrt{5} - \sqrt{11} - 63 \sqrt{55}\right) + \nu\,\left(5479-3061 \sqrt{5}-4723 \sqrt{11}-1341 \sqrt{55}\right)\!,\\[2mm]
\sigma &= 2\cdot 11^3 \cdot 811 \left(11-2 \sqrt{11}\right)\\
&- \kappa\left(13673 - 2431 \sqrt{5} - 4514 \sqrt{11} - 120 \sqrt{55}\right) -\lambda \left(172406+140252 \sqrt{5}-23673 \sqrt{11}-31171 \sqrt{55}\right) \\
&+ \mu\left(3179+143 \sqrt{5}-798 \sqrt{11}-180 \sqrt{55}\right)
   - \nu\left(15896 - 1642 \sqrt{5} - 6967 \sqrt{11} + 1035 \sqrt{55}\right)\!,\\[2mm]
\tau &= 2\cdot11^3\cdot811 \left(20 \sqrt{11} - 33\right) + 6\cdot11 \sqrt{3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot811 \,\eta }\\
&+ \kappa\left(166573+3025 \sqrt{5} - 49167 \sqrt{11} - 2979 \sqrt{55}\right) \\
&+2\,\lambda \left(576143+229934 \sqrt{5}-195022 \sqrt{11}-64418 \sqrt{55}\right) \\
&+ \mu\left(2453-2035 \sqrt{5}-505
   \sqrt{11}-113 \sqrt{55}\right)\\
&+\nu\left(292348+26650 \sqrt{5}-75990 \sqrt{11}-2062 \sqrt{55}\right)\!.
\end{align}
$$
Then the root can be represented as
$$\small\gamma = \frac1{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11^3\cdot811}\left(\rho +11^2 \cdot 2^{1/3} \cdot 5^{2/3} \cdot 811^{2/3} \cdot \tau^{1/3} + 11 \cdot 2^{2/3} \cdot 5^{1/3} \cdot 811^{1/3} \cdot \tau^{-1/3} \cdot \sigma \right)\!.$$

*Mathematica* expression is [here](https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/e819da80c193fd0f496a20fa4749620e).

---

I obtained this form by factoring Steven's 30-degree polynomial over rationals extended with $\sqrt{11}$ and a root of Tito's solvable quintic $-23 - 343u + 390 u^2 - 42u^3 - 15u^4 + u^5$ (I solved it as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134551/7288)). It factored into a product of cubics over that extension, which were easy to solve. The most difficult part was simplification of the result to a form that fits on one page. $811$ is a magical prime number that for some reason appears many times throughout the result.

Comment: It is no surprise that the $30$-deg equation is solvable by radical. As I proved, the value of $\gamma$ lies in field $K(E[22])$, which is generated by $22$-torsion for $E: y^2 = 4x^3-x$, but $E$ has CM by $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$, so $K(E[22])/K$ is abelian.

Comment: Also because $j(E)\in \mathbb{Q}$, it should not be difficult to show $\gamma \in K(E[11])$, which is also the ray class field modulo $11$, whose degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be computed, it predicts accurately the degree of $\gamma$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $30$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Do you expect polynomials of higher degrees arising from the inverse Beta regularized to be also solvable in radicals?

Comment: Any idea why $811$ appears all over the result? Or it just happens so?

Comment: For any rational $0<r<1$, the algebraic $\gamma$ in $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\sqrt[4]{1-x\,\gamma^2}}=r\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2\gamma}}$$ is solvable by radical. I need sometime to contemplate the genesis of $811$ though.

Comment: Sometimes posts on the Mathematics Stack exchange just deserve to be in papers.

Answer (score 3):

It seems solving $I(\beta^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})=\frac1N$ also solves $I(\gamma^2;\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{4})=\frac1N$ as they involve *reciprocal polynomials*. So again following Nemo's lead in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2040809/4781), we employ the duplication formula,
$$\frac{1}{2}I(p^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})=I(1-q^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})$$ 
where $p,q$ are related by the $8$-deg,
$$p^2 (-1 + 2 q + q^2)^4 = 16 q (-1 + q^2) (1 + q^2)^2\tag1$$
So given a solution to $\displaystyle I(\beta^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})= \frac{1}{2^n N}$ for $n=0$, the duplication formula enables us to find ***infinitely*** many  for $n\geq1$.

For example, the solution to $I(p^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{3}$ is $p = 1-\sqrt3$. One can then solve for $I(\beta^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{6}$ by plugging the known $p$ into $(1)$.