# How to generalize Reshetnikov's $\arg\,B\left(\frac{-5+8\,\sqrt{-11}}{27};\,\frac12,\frac13\right)=\frac\pi3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, closed-form, beta-function

We have,
$$\arg z_1 = \frac{k\,\pi}3, \quad z_1 = \left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)^k\tag1$$
$$\arg z_2=\frac{k\,\pi}3, \quad z_2 = \left( B\Big(\color{blue}{\tfrac{-5+8\,\sqrt{-11}}{27}};\,\tfrac12,\tfrac13\Big)\right)^k \tag2$$
for $k=1,2,3$ and *incomplete beta function* $B(z;a,b)$. [The second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687567/closed-form-for-2f-1-left-frac12-frac23-frac32-frac8-sqrt11-i-5) with $k=1$ is by V. Reshetnikov. But that cannot be an isolated result.

Reshetnikov states (without giving details) that $(2)$ is equivalent to,
$$B\left(\frac19;\,\frac16,\frac13\right) = \frac12\,B\left(\frac16,\frac13\right)
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac16\right)\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\tag3$$
Thus, $(3)$ is related to,
$$I\left(\color{blue}{\frac19};\,\frac16,\frac13\right)=\frac12 \tag4$$
with *regularized beta function* $I(z;a,b)$. The equation
$$I\left(z;\,\frac16,\frac13\right)=\frac1n \tag5$$
is quite easy to solve. For example, the smallest real root of,
$$-1 + 99 z - 243 z^2 + 81 z^3= 0\tag6$$
will yield $n=3$. More specifically,
$$I\left(\frac19\Big(1-4\sin\big(\tfrac{\pi}{18}\big)\Big)^2;\,\frac16,\frac13 \right)=\frac13\quad\quad\tag7$$
$$\quad I\left(\frac13\Big(1-\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt[4]3}\Big)^2;\,\frac16,\frac13\right) =\frac14\quad\tag8$$
and so on.

> **Q:** But how do we get from $\color{blue}{\frac19}$ of $(4)$ to $\color{blue}{\frac{-5+8\,\sqrt{-11}}{27}}$ of $(2)$? (I assume a hypergeometric transformation is involved.)

If the answer can be found, then perhaps we can use an expression $P(z)$ of a root $z$ of $(6)$ to find some,
$$\arg\,B\left( P(z);\,\frac12,\frac13\right)=\beta\,\pi\tag7$$
where $\beta$ is a rational/algebraic number?

Comment: The exponent in $(2)$ should be inside $\arg$, no?

Comment: @J.M.: I rephrased it for clarity. :)