# On Reshetnikov's integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x\ \sqrt[6]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\,\alpha^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}\,|\alpha|}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, experimental-mathematics

V. Reshetnikov gave the [remarkable integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538564/conjecture-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x-left-sqrt6),
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x\,\sqrt[6]{1-x}\,\sqrt{1-x\left(\sqrt{6}\sqrt{12+7\sqrt3}-3\sqrt3-6\right)^2}}=\frac\pi9(3+\sqrt2\sqrt[4]{27})\tag1$$
More generally, given some integer/rational $N$, we are to find an algebraic number $\alpha$ that solves,

> $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x\ \sqrt[6]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\,\alpha^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}\,|\alpha|}\tag2$$

and absolute value $|\alpha|$. (*Compare to the similar integral in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037412/on-the-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt4x-sqrt1-x-sqrt41-x-alpha2)*.) Equivalently, to find $\alpha$ such that,

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{N}
&=I\left(\alpha^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)\\[1.8mm]
&= \frac{B\left(\alpha^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)}{B\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)}\\
&=B\left(\alpha^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac56\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)}\end{aligned} \tag3$$

with [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $\beta(a,b)$, [incomplete beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $\beta(z;a,b)$ and [regularized beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html) $I(z;a,b)$. 
Solutions $\alpha$ for $N=2,3,4,5,7$ are known. Let,
$$\alpha=\frac{-3^{1/2}+v^{1/2}}{3^{-1/2}+v^{1/2}}\tag4$$
Then,
$$ - 3 + 6 v + v^2 = 0, \quad N = 2\\ 
- 3 + 27 v - 33v^2 + v^3 = 0, \quad N = 3\\
3^2 - 150 v^2 + 120 v^3 + 5 v^4 = 0, \quad N = 5\\ 
- 3^3 - 54 v + 1719 v^2 - 3492v^3 - 957 v^4 + 186 v^5 + v^6 = 0, \quad N = 7$$

and (*added later*),

$$3^4 - 648 v + 1836 v^2 + 1512 v^3 - 13770 v^4 + 12168 v^5 - 7476 v^6 + 408 v^7 + v^8 = 0,\quad N=4$$

using the largest positive root, respectively. The example was just $N=2$, while $N=4$ leads to,

$$I\left(\tfrac{1-\alpha}{2};\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}\right)=\tfrac{3}{8},\quad\quad I\left(\tfrac{1+\alpha}{2};\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}\right)=\tfrac{5}{8}$$

I found these using *Mathematica*'s *FindRoot* command, and some hints from Reshetnikov's and other's works, but as much as I tried, I couldn't find prime $N=11$.

> **Q:** Is it true one can find algebraic number $\alpha$ for all $N$? What is it for $N=11$?

Comment: Do you know about the [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html) function? It tries to find the simplest algebraic number matching a numeric approximation. It likes to be given quite a lot of correct decimal digits, though. From my experience, if the degree $>8$, then you need to provide $>200$ digits.

Comment: I used `RootApproximant[N[InverseBetaRegularized[1/7, 1/2, 1/3], 250]]` to find my conjectures. Had no luck with `1/11`. I got results for dozens of other fractions though.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: These "dozens" of fractions, did you get unit fractions other than $p=2,3,5,7$?

Comment: With `InverseBetaRegularized[1/n, 1/2, 1/3]` -- no. But `InverseBetaRegularized[1/6,1/3,1/3]`, `InverseBetaRegularized[1/4,1/4,1/2]` and others seem to be algebraic. No fraction with a denominator $>7$ produced an apparently algebraic number.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: There seems to be a denominator $>7$ that yields an algebraic number, namely $InverseBetaRegularized[\color{blue}{1/8},1/4,1/2]$ which is a palindromic 32-deg eqn with discriminant $d=2^{2064}$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: InverseBetaRegularized[1/8,1/3,1/3] also seems to be an algebraic number, deg-16.

Comment: Hasn't achille hui in his answer already showed that $\alpha$ is algebraic for all rational $N$? In his notations we have $\sqrt[3]{1-\alpha^2}=\frac{4}{\eta^2}\wp\left(i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2N}\right)$. We also know that $\wp\left(i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2N}\right)=\wp\left(\frac{2\omega_2-\omega_1}{N}\right)$. Now addition theorem for $\wp$ shows that $\wp\left(\frac{2\omega_2-\omega_1}{N}\right)/\eta^2$ is algebraic for all rational $N$, which means that $\alpha$ is also algebraic.

Comment: @Nemo: I guess I missed that part. However, half of the question is to find the explicit minimal polynomial of the tricky $N=11$ and perhaps provide an explanation of its presumably high degree.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Can you give an explicit polynomial for `InverseBetaRegularized[1/8, 1/4, 1/2]`?

Comment: I found an explicit form for `InverseBetaRegularized[1/8, 1/3, 1/3]`: http://mathb.in/109745

Comment: It appears that `InverseBetaRegularized[1/11, 1/3, 1/3]` is $\left(1-\sqrt{1-4\alpha}\right)/2,$ where $\alpha$ is the root of the polynomial $\small 11 \alpha ^{20}-23221 \alpha ^{19}-1153603 \alpha ^{18}+62045313 \alpha ^{17}+66133914 \alpha ^{16}+1596123771 \alpha ^{15}-8579472693 \alpha ^{14}+4760052033
   \alpha ^{13}-22319781 \alpha ^{12}-8054721004 \alpha ^{11}+10595519759 \alpha ^{10}-4869514969 \alpha ^9+1106263389 \alpha ^8-189881835 \alpha ^7+59389374 \alpha
   ^6-17393277 \alpha ^5+2270301 \alpha ^4-102729 \alpha ^3+605 \alpha ^2+242 \alpha -1$ in the interval $0<\alpha<1/6$.

Comment: It also appears that `InverseBetaRegularized[1/11, 1/2, 1/3]` is $\alpha^2,$ where $\alpha$ is an algebraic number of degree $40$ whose minimal polynomial and isolating interval are given [here](http://mathb.in/109773).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: Beautiful! Would you like to put that as an answer?

Comment: Oh, I have no proof yet.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: I tested your deg 40 and it involves the **solvable** quintic $\small 16671744 - 36246528 x - 12153024  x^2 - 198432  x^3 + 2808  x^4 + x^5=0$ which is cyclic and whose discriminant is divisible by $11^4\times23^4$. I guess $\alpha$, in addition to being algebraic numbers (by achille), are in fact also **radicals** hence their minpoly has a solvable Galois group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49464/discussion-between-vladimir-reshetnikov-and-tito-piezas-iii).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: I was about to post the explicit polynomial for InverseBetaRegularized[1/8, 1/4, 1/2] when I noticed an interesting pattern. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040398/an-unsual-pattern-for-the-regularized-beta-function-i-alpha-frac14-frac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment. And courtesy of V. Reshetnikov's result [here](http://mathb.in/109773), though as he points out it is tentative*.)

The algebraic number $\alpha$ that solves,

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x\ \sqrt[6]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\,\alpha^2}}=\frac{1}{11}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}\;\alpha}$$

seems to have a $40$-deg minpoly. However, it turns out we can also reduce its degree and express it using the common form above. Let,

$$\alpha=\frac{3^{1/2}-v^{1/2}}{3^{-1/2}+v^{1/2}}$$

where $v$ is a the ***second*** largest positive root ($r_9$ in *Mathematica* syntax) of,

$$\small P(v)=-3^{10} + 23816430 v^2 - 323903448 v^3 + 2177615583 v^4 - 9297934272 v^5 + 25869358152 v^6 - 37475802144 v^7 - 16459141842 v^8 + 180065426112 v^9 - 
  338100745356 v^{10} + 329418595440 v^{11} - 211367836746 v^{12} + 
  102243404736 v^{13} - 8162926200 v^{14} - 9999738144 v^{15} + 
  1006439643 v^{16} - 134177472 v^{17} - 2246706 v^{18} + 30888 v^{19} + 
  11 v^{20} = 0$$

Also,

$$I\big(\alpha^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3}\big)=\tfrac{1}{5}\,I\big(\tfrac{1-\alpha}{2};\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}\big)=\tfrac{1}{6}\,I\big(\tfrac{1+\alpha}{2};\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}\big)=\frac{1}{11}$$

with regularized beta function $I(z;a,b)$. Furthermore, if

$$y =\frac{r_1+r_9+r_{13}+r_{14}}{12}$$

then $y$ is a root of the solvable quintic,

$$67 - 1748 y - 7033 y^2 - 1378 y^3 + 234 y^4 + y^5=0$$

with discriminant divisible by $11^4\times23^4$. Using the other quartic symmetric polynomials show that the $20$-deg is just a quartic in disguise, hence is solvable. All these suggest that $P(v)$ is the correct polynomial for $N=11$.

Answer (score 2):

> **I. Duplication**

Following Nemo's lead in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2040809/4781), we find the formula,
$$\frac{1}{2}I(p^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3})=I(1+q^3;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3})$$ 
where $p,q$ are related by the $12$-deg,
$$p^2(-2 + 2 q + q^2)^6 = 36(1 + q^3) (4 + 4 q + 6 q^2 - 2 q^3 + q^4)^2$$
This then enables us to find ***infinitely*** many $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n N}$.

For example, since $I(p^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{3}$ is known, then solving for $I(\alpha^2;\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{6}$ turns out to involve a $36$-deg equation.

> **II. Triplication**

(*Courtesy of Nemo*.) Starting with,
$$B\left(z;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right)=2 \sqrt{z} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{3}{2};z\right).
$$
The transformation
$$
\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{3 z \left(1-\frac{z}{9}\right)^2}{(1-z)^2}\right)=\frac{(1-z) \, }{1-\frac{z}{9}}{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{3}{2};z\right)
$$
applied two times gives
$$
\frac{1}{3} B\left({\frac{(9-z)^2 z \left(z^3+225 z^2-405 z+243\right)^2}{729 (1-z)^2 (z+3)^6}};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right)=B\left(z;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\right).
$$