# Why do these two integrals use roots of reciprocal polynomials?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, closed-form, beta-function

There is the nice [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538564/conjecture-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x-left-sqrt6) by V. Reshetnikov,
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x\ \sqrt[6]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\,\alpha^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}\;\alpha}\tag1$$

also discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037060/on-reshetnikovs-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x). By direct analogy, we can consider its cousin,

> $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt[4]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\,\beta^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2}\;\beta}\tag{2a}$$

and the [version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037412/on-the-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt4x-sqrt1-x-sqrt41-x-alpha2) investigated also by Reshetnikov,

> $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt{1-x}\ \sqrt[4]{1-x\,\gamma^2}}=\frac{1}{N}\,\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2\gamma}}\tag{2b}$$

Given some integer/rational $N$, it entails finding algebraic numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that,

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{N}=I\left(\alpha^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)= \frac{B\left(\alpha^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)}{B\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac13\right)}
\end{aligned} $$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{N}=I\left(\beta^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac14\right)= \frac{B\left(\beta^2;\ \tfrac12,\tfrac14\right)}{B\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac14\right)}\\
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{N}=I\left(\gamma^2;\ \tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)= \frac{B\left(\gamma^2;\ \tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)}{B\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac14\right)}\\
\end{aligned}$$

with [regularized beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html) $I(z;a,b)$, [incomplete beta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $B(z;a,b)$, and [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $B(a,b)$. Solutions for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ for $N=2,3,5,7,11$ are known, for the latter two as,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
N & P(\beta)=0 &P(\gamma)=0 \\
\hline
2 & -4 + 4 \beta^2 + \beta^4 & -1 + 2 \gamma^2\\
3 & -2 - 2 \beta + \beta^2 & - 1 + 2 \gamma + 2 \gamma^2\\
5 & -4 + 8 \beta + 4 \beta^2 - 8 \beta^3 + \beta^4 & - 1 + 8 \gamma - 4 \gamma^2 - 8 \gamma^3 + 4 \gamma^4\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

with $N=7$ a $12$-deg, and $N=11$ [a $30$-deg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037412/on-the-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt4x-sqrt1-x-sqrt41-x-alpha2), both reciprocals. (Polynomials for $\alpha$ are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037060/on-reshetnikovs-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt3x-sqrt61-x-sqrt1-x).)

> **Q:** For $\beta$ and $\gamma$, why are they roots of ***reciprocal polynomials*** when $N=3,5,7,11$ (and presumably others), but ***different*** polynomials when $N=2$?

**Ex.** For $N=5$ and using $(2a)$ yields the succinct $\beta = 1-\tan\tfrac{3\pi}{20}$ hence,
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]x\ \sqrt[4]{1-x}\ \sqrt{1-x\big(1-\tan\tfrac{3\pi}{20}\big)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\pi}{5\big(1-\tan\tfrac{3\pi}{20}\big)}$$

Comment: In accordance with the theme of algebraic numbers, $\tan\frac{3\pi}{20}=\sqrt{5}-1-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: @Nemo: If interested, I've asked a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041898/on-the-integral-int-01-fracdx-sqrt4x-sqrt41-x-sqrt1-x-beta2).

Comment: By the way, I found an explicit form for the 12-degree root with $N=7$: $\small\frac16\left(5 \cos \alpha-\sqrt{3} \sin \alpha-1-\sqrt3\sqrt{7+4 \sqrt{7}-\left(11+2 \sqrt{7}\right) \cos \alpha+\sqrt{3} \left(5+2 \sqrt{7}\right) \sin \alpha}\right),\;\alpha=\frac13\arccos\left(\frac{13}{14}\right)$, around $0.07005154493...$

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: Very nice! Thanks for letting me know.